# how to get current time from videojs.wavesurfer

Tags: video.js

I want to get the current time, within the video being played when I click within the audio waveform.
I'm playing a video stream, I want to be able to pause, then add a note to a table about something within the video. So I need to get the currentTime.
I merge an audio stream with the video and play in a div.

```
     let options = {
                controls: true,
                bigPlayButton: false,
                autoplay: false,
                loop: false,
                fluid: false,
                width: 1000,
                height: 200,
                plugins: {
                    // enable videojs-wavesurfer plugin
                    wavesurfer: {
                        // configure videojs-wavesurfer
                        backend: 'MediaElement',
                        displayMilliseconds: true,
                        debug: true,
                        waveColor: 'black',
                        progressColor: 'purple',
                        cursorColor: 'yellow',
                        hideScrollbar: true,
                        // put waveform in separate container
                        container: '#waveform'
                    }
                }
            };
   let videoplayer = videojs('myClip', options, function() {
                let videofile = $("#mergedVideo").text()
                console.log(" Playing "+videofile)
                // load wav file from url
               videoplayer.src({src: videofile, type: 'video/mp4'});

            });
// Here is the pause... always gives an error.. 
            videoplayer.on('pause', function () {
                let currenttime = videoplayer.getCurrentTime();
                $('#currentTime').text(currenttime);
                alert(" PAUSED ")
            });
```

but i'm getting videoplayer.getCurrentTime is not a function in console. I have this working perfectly for just audio streams.
Any help would be grealty appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's `currentTime()`. There's a `getCurrentTime()` on the lower level tech abstraction, but you shouldn't (need to) use it directly.